# Planning an exception handling strategy in advance

Tags: c#, .net, exception

When I look at a method in the .NET Framework, it can throw several possible exceptions.

From a planning perspective, what do I need to ask to plan and handle these exceptions? I understand that depending on the impact of an exception, that would influence showing it in the UI layer. For example, if a process at the back end which is opaque to the user experience throws an exception, you would not want to show that to the user as s/he would have no idea what that is.

Thanks

Comment: The managed VS compiler put a default exception handler at top of execution stack so any unhandled exception in the code get caught by the default handler.  So putting an exception hanlder in main would catch all exception not caught by other handlers in the code and will stop the default handler from displaying unwanted exceptions messages.

Answer (score 0):

You'd normally have a business logic layer in your application, and you'd wrap the methods in that library in safe calls.  Those methods may even say what exceptions they can throw, and you may want to handle those exceptions in a unique way if you so wish.

Here's an example of a couple of classes that can handle both unexpected and custom exceptions:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodInvokationResult result = SafeActionInvokator.HandleSafely(() =>
        {
            MyFakeBusinessEngine.DivideTwoNumbers(5, 0);
        });
        if (result.Exception is System.DivideByZeroException)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"A divide by zerp exception was caught");
        }
        else if (!result.Success)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"An unknown error occured.");
        }
    }
}
```

^ You can see that you can wrap the calls and handle them in a sensible way.

```
public class MethodInvokationResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; set; }
}
```

^ A simple result class

```
public static class MyFakeBusinessEngine
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Divides two numbers
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">numerator</param>
    /// <param name="b">denominator</param>
    /// <returns>the result</returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.DivideByZeroException">When b is zero, divide by zero exception is thrown.</exception>
    public static int DivideTwoNumbers(int a, int b)
    {
        return a / b;
    }
}
```

^ A well documented method, that even tells other developers what exceptions it expects to throw

```
public static class SafeActionInvokator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a method, and if any exception is thrown, will log the error and swallow the exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="methodToExecute"></param>
    public static MethodInvokationResult HandleSafely(Action methodToExecute)
    {
        try
        {
            methodToExecute.Invoke();
            return new MethodInvokationResult()
            {
                Exception = null,
                Success = true
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{ex}");
            return new MethodInvokationResult()
            {
                Exception = ex,
                Success = false
            };
        }
    }
}
```

^ The wrapper for the method you call, wrapping this in a try catch allows you to handle all exceptions in the same way, or put any custom logic you'd like in there.

This can be expanded to be a call that can return any actual result value too.  You could make a generic result class instead of the simple one I've shown.

FINALLY!  As to your actual question, I'd create some of these layers throughout your application, and re-throw any exceptions with a severity rating included.  These would propagate to your UI layer and you can chose what to do based on Severity.

Maybe even something like this!

```
public class MajorException : Exception { }
public class MediumException : Exception { }
public class MinorException : Exception { }
public class UserError : Exception { }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's a pretty handy technique, thanks! So for example, if there is a critical file in the application that is deleted (like a config file) and then the application tries to open it, that would be a major (or fatal) exception. In that case, I'd close the application. What I am looking to do is do a flow chart that will depict the actions I should take in exception based on their nature.

Comment: Flow chart eh?  I highly recommend yEd Graph Editor - totally free and it's awesome.  I use it at work!  As long as you can define what exceptions you're expecting you can handle them, it takes some human brain power to recognise what could go wrong with a line of code or block of code, for example the file access one you mentioned.  If you can anticipate it, you can handle it.  Heck, you can anticipate total meltdown, as long as the exception is safely handled, your app can continue.

Comment: I should add...  You might want to consider what to do when something fails, which might mean rolling back a previous operation.  This could get hairy, but there's a UnitOfWork pattern you could use, maybe leveraging the Transaction pattern that the DotNet framework provides...  I digress.

Comment: In my case, the app;ication is ASP.NET and is revolving around the creation and management of AD accounts. Most operations only get commited to AD if the Save() method is called, so no possibility of intermediate state. Another question I have - I can only see two options in exception handlng - logging and telling the user - when you "handle" an exception, is there every anything else to do? And if you do rollback an operation, would this go in the catch or finally block?

Comment: Definitely worth you researching the unit of work pattern and the built-in transaction system, a great place to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Oh, and here for transactions too: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions(v=vs.110).aspx  .  You could merge the transaction stuff into the code I've shown you, placing the rollback in the finally of the try-catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to write it as a comment but it is to long for the comment textbox...

1. There are exceptions that are important to show the users because they can handle it by themselves, for example: file name is illegal.
2. There are exceptions that i find important to show the users because they (the users) will function as my QA team, for example: some method will not update the GUI and they probably will get to the conclusion that they should report that further on, they will show me the exception and i will discover that my array is out of bounds...
3. there are exceptions that promoting them to the user will just confuse them and like you said

> "s/he would have no idea what that is"

for example, For example:

> "if a process at the back end which is opaque throws an exception".

those exception i am saving for myself (in database..)..
I am always reminding myself that the end user has a different psychology compare to a developer (-:

I hope i understood your question in the right manner.